# Call four operation at the same time

Tags: java, eclipse

I have four methods that I should execute them at the same time
so,My question is:

Is it possible in java to call four operation at the same time(in parallel manner)?

Comment: Start with [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: Create threads and launch...

Comment: How many processors do you have? :)

Comment: You mean concurrent, parallelism need one CPU/core per process... Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: I have one processor @MarounMaroun

Comment: thank you @JunedAhsan should I need to add more processors to work with thread in java? just because I would like to call four operations of class at the same time

Comment: @Chriss No you can run multiple threads spawned from a single process on a single processor. Threads will take turn to get the processor time, but all the threads should get time slices to work in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those methods take a long time, you should create multiple [threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).
If they don't, you can run them one by one.

Comment: thank you @Robin Dijkhof for kind help.No, they don't take long time.does that mean I don't need to use threads in java and just perform them in sequential manner?